# How to create a QNX neutrino 7.0.0 bootable cd image with Photon?

Tags: boot, rtos, qnx, qnx-neutrino, bootable

I am a newbie in QNX and I have a question:
How to generate a QNX 7.0.0 bootable image for x86 (32-bit) that I can burn on a CD disk and boot with Photon.
There is an ISO image on the internet that does exactly that I want to. It called "QNX demo" or so, but it's not QNX 7, it uses a earlier version, and also it's a ready result, with no easy posibility to add my software to.

Also, I am not sure that it's possible to generate a ISO image using "QNX system builder" - the only way I can boot something (that is not even nearly close to what I need) - is generating a sort of multiboot image and booting it via GRUB2+mkresue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photon isn't available in SDP 7, it was deprecated (notice indicating intent to remove in a future version) in SDP 6.5 SP1 and was removed from the product in SDP 6.6. The replacement graphics technology is QNX Screen, which is available for 6.5 and 6.6, and well as being in 7.0, but it is intended for embedded use and does not include a user desktop environment like Photon does.

Comment: I have updated my question, so it's about booting to shell now. If you know more, please review it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429377/how-to-create-a-qnx-neutrino-7-0-0-bootable-cd-image