# How to create a QNX neutrino 7.0.0 bootable cd image?

Tags: x86, qnx, qnx-neutrino, bootable, qnx-ifs

I am a newbie in QNX and I have a question: How to generate a QNX 7.0.0 bootable image for x86 (32-bit) that I can burn on a CD disk and boot on my pc? I have asked a question that looks similar to this, but it was about booting with Photon graphics, but as user "v836" mentioned, it's outdated, so this question is about booting to "just console" QNX with full set of unix utilities, hdd detection/mounting support, networking and (if possible) c compiller.

I will be glad if somebody have a link to set of buildconfigs sor QNX 7.0.0 for different tasks that includes the one I need.

There is an ISO image on the internet that does exactly that I want to. It called "QNX demo" or so, but it's not QNX 7, it uses a earlier version, and also it's a ready result, with no easy posibility to add my software to.

Also, I am not sure that it's possible to generate a ISO image using "QNX system builder" - the only way I can boot something (that is not even nearly close to what I need) - is generating a sort of multiboot image and booting it via GRUB2+mkresue.